# How do you add the 'Edit View' Links?

Tags: views, navigation, blocks

How do you add the 'Edit View' Links in the gear icon that appears when you hover the mouse over a block. I can see "Configure Block" but I want also "Edit View" option.
I know these icons are the output from the Contextual links module that comes with Drupal core so I'm not sure how to merge the two to be used on 1 block.

Comment: Are you sure the block you're talking about is a view?

Comment: It's a regular block. I'm trying to add the "Edit View" option to it.

Comment: You'll only see "Edit View" if the block is provided by the Views module. It wouldn't make sense otherwise. Or do you mean you want to add one manually and link that specific block to a specific view?

Answer (score 1):

Can you Please Check this, Hope its help you. https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/contextual